# Can we create cycles in Airflow DAG with exit condition?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

We have a huge CSV file, and the airflow DAG looks like

```
>> read_csv 
>> apply filter
>> store in database
```

we have to pass the data from the CSV reader operator to the filter operator. Instead of reading the complete CSV and giving it to the filter,  can we use the following workflow?

```
>> read_chunk_from_csv
>> apply filter
>> store in database
>> [read_chunk_from_csv, exit]
```

can we read a chunk from CSV iteratively and process every chunk in the cycle until the completion.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. DAG stands for Direct Acyclic Graph which means no cycles.

Should you try, it Airflow will raise [`AirflowDagCycleException`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/165945250b62b86efe4f88c6ae8005883a29f2fd/airflow/exceptions.py#L135-L136)

What you are looking for is MapReduce like behavior. For that you can use [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#dynamic-task-mapping) this feature was released in Airflow 2.3.0 you can use it to created mapped tasks where each one of them handles portion of the data.